# HTML checkbox-value both checked and disabled

Tags: php, html

I have a HTML-Table where I got checkboxes. With PHP I let these checkboxes know their value, to see if they are checked or not. I read this information out of a Database.

Now I want to set the value of a checkbox disabled and checked if I read that it's checked. Obviously, my checkbox is just disabled with the code I have, how can I get both attributes.

```
        $checkbox[0] = 'checked';
        $checkbox[0] = disabled;
        <input type='checkbox' name="box1" id="checked1" <?php echo $checkbox[0]; ?>/>
```

Comment: You are overwriting your property, setting it from checked to disabled. You can set it disabled by just adding `disabled` to the element `<input type='checkbox' name="box1" id="checked1" disabled <?php $checkbox[0] ?? '''; ?> />`

Comment: firstly, disabled needs to be wrapped in quotes. Secondly, change your array index so they differ. It's currently being overwritten.

Comment: `$checkbox[0] = disabled;` will throw a Warning. smth like 'use of undefined constant'

Comment: Also as the the others have said, like 2 will error - I just assumed that it was a typo in the SO editor, but that could be an issue for you...

Comment: I know that now i just overwrite the value, but if i just type disabled into my html tag, it is disabled constantly. I just want to disable it, if it´s checked.

Comment: Do i have to use GetElementbyTagName or is there an easier way?

Comment: disabled works without quotes btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need both set, you need to add them together (using `.=` in this case)before insert them into the HTML...

```
$checkbox[0] = 'checked';
$checkbox[0] .= ' disabled';
<input type='checkbox' name="box1" id="checked1" <?php echo $checkbox[0]; ?>/>
```

Note the quotes round `disabled` - BUT also a space, otherwise when you add the two together you will get `checkeddisabled`.

Also not sure why you have `$checkbox[0]`, you could just use `$checkbox` but as I don't know I am just putting this as a suggestion.

If you want it to have both values with no other logic, you could simplify it to be...

```
$checkbox[0] = 'checked disabled';
<input type='checkbox' name="box1" id="checked1" <?php echo $checkbox[0]; ?>/>
```